# Runas different user in a batch File

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file that will start and run a application at start up, but I think I am running into a problem. I want to put this batch file in my startup folder to run every time it gets turned on.

I have created this code below that would run the command prompt as a local admin when I am on the network. But if I am not on the network I get a an error saying:

> there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

Now when I go to run it manually, like with my mouse then I would put a `.\` before the local admin account username and then it will work fine. 
I guess I am trying to do that type of step with this batch file.

This code will help me restart my virus scanner so I sign on to a VPN for work, since my virus scanner keeps getting disabled.

My code:

```
runas /savecred /user:n005397t "CD C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise start restartvse.exe"
```

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14998991/62576) may help.

Answer (score 0):

`o°/`

Firstly, you might be better off looking into *why* your virus scanner keeps getting disabled.  That's often a sign of a rootkit or some other treachery.  I think you ought to let your IT staff diagnose and correct this issue for you.

If you still want to script the Band-Aid workaround as you are attempting to do, then I suggest it might be a more graceful solution to use scheduled tasks.  You can schedule a task to start on startup or on logon, whichever you feel is more appropriate; and that task can be scheduled to run with another user's credentials.  You could use `schtasks.exe /create` to do this, but since you only need to do it once there's no reason not to use the GUI (Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Task Scheduler).

I wish you'd just let your IT staff handle it, though.  Continuing to operate an infected machine online is like going to a movie theater with the flu.  It's inconsiderate to everyone else.

Comment: haha I am the IT Staff. I am trying to work on a workaround solution for time being.

Comment: @user2795514 ... oh.  Well, in your attempted command it appears you're trying to mash multiple commands into one `runas`.  Take out the `CD` for certain.  Now, are `start` and `restartsvc.exe` two separate commands?  Or is `start` part of the path name?  I suspect the command you're trying to land on is `runas /savecred /user:%computername%\n005397t "C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\restartvse.exe"`.  But if I were you I wouldn't be satisfied until the root cause was addressed.  Reimage if you have to.